# Is it a common view among Christains that Satan is the lord of this world?

Tags: satan, gospel-of-matthew

As I drove past a church (not sure the denomination) on a country road, the sign out front read "Satan is the lord of this world. Be careful!" Is this a widely accepted view?

If so, how do we explain Matthew 28:18-20 where a resurrected Jesus says "All power in heaven and on earth has been given to me"?

Comment: Knowing which denomination the church was is the first step in doing your research.

Comment: @DoubleU "Is this a widely accepted view?" Sounds like a overview question to me. I think the question is plenty answerable.

Comment: @fredsbend I'd prefer that the asker is more specific than that, narrowing down to Trinitarian and Nicene Christians.

Answer (score 2):

According to apostle Paul in Bible, Satan is the "god" of this world [2 Cor 4:4](http://biblehub.com/2_corinthians/4-4.htm) 
However the term "god of this world" means the ruler, the one who is being worshiped or obeyed. Satan got that title by deceiving the first Adam and leading him to sin against God (Genesis 3).

However like you said at the resurrection, all power was given to Jesus Matthew 28:18-20 and he gave us back his (power) name (to the church, every born again believer) and at the mention of the name of Jesus that we have received EVERY knees shall bow in heaven, on earth and under the earth [Philippians 2:10](http://biblehub.com/philippians/2-10.htm). Which means, **Satan is the "god" of this world and we (born again believers) are "god over Satan and the World"**. That is why demons flee when we cast them out using the name of Jesus.

In a nutshell, those who have accepted Jesus as their Lord and Savior (Rom 10:9/John 1:12) are the "god of this world". They have authority. So, the church sign board that you saw.. It depends on what they meant by Satan being the Lord of this world.

Comment: If this is so, Why are God's people still suffering in this world?

Comment: Simply because Bible says in John 10:10 that The thief comes only to steal and kill and destroy. The devil is a warrior, a Cherub trained for war (Ezekiel 28:14) though he has been defeated, he is still trying to use tricks to defeat Christians (Eph 6:12). It is just like a Father leaves a car for his son as inheritance and someone else comes to the son and try to steal the car or take it by force. If the son does not do anything against it, the thief will have his way. And christians today are idle

Comment: What about martyrs?  Would you say they were idle too?

Comment: By Christians, i meant the majority of Christians. Martyrs died for Christ which is an honorable death with great reward. Bible talks about those who were beheaded (Rev 20:4). But it is not dying for christ that makes you active, it is preaching the Gospel and making disciples (Matthew 28:19)

Answer (score 1):

**Is it a common view among Christians that Satan is the lord of this world?**

It is a Biblical view, it may not be as widespread as one would think as many "worldly" Christian churches would not want to emphasize this perspective.

> Ephesians 2:2  Wherein in time past ye walked according to the course
>   of this world, according to the prince of the power of the air, the
>   spirit that now worketh in the children of disobedience:
>
> 2 Corinthians 4:3-4  But if our gospel be hid, it is hid to them that
>   are lost:   In whom the god of this world hath blinded the minds of
>   them which believe not, lest the light of the glorious gospel of
>   Christ, who is the image of God, should shine unto them.
>
> John 14:30  Hereafter I will not talk much with you: for the prince of
>   this world cometh, and hath nothing in me.
>
> James 4:4  Ye adulterers and adulteresses, know ye not that the
>   friendship of the world is enmity with God? whosoever therefore will
>   be a friend of the world is the enemy of God.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the context behind the sign stating this, it is difficult to say if it is a common view.

**Did they mean that Satan is the Lord of this world because the majority of this world have chosen to follow him? or do they mean Satan has ultimate authority in this world?** Most Christians would not object to the first view, but the later is uncommon. As you said, Matthew 28:18-20 shows that all power was given to Jesus.

Ironically, if Satan has ultimate authority on earth, how are we to "be careful" as the sign suggests when we are completely defenseless against him?

In the Bible, it is written that we cannot serve two masters (Matthew 6:24) - either we serve God or we serve Satan. True obedience to God is difficult, because when Satan comes to us, he comes home. In our natural sinful nature, our enmity is against God. However, **God has promised us from the beginning that He'd put enmity between us and Satan**, between the woman and the serpent (Genesis 3:15). This was the plan of salvation set from the foundation of the world. So to all who will to serve God by grace through faith, it is possible. We are not the "god of this world", but we are the adopted sons of God through Jesus.

> Submit yourselves therefore to God. Resist the devil, and he will flee
>   from you. (James 4:7)

This is easier said than done, every willful sin must be overcome. So God allows us to enter into trails, into open warfare against Satan, so that we can see what is in our hearts and be humbled, receive His preparation, and **win**.